# Prerender static site

Tags: server-side-rendering, static-site, stenciljs, eleventy

I'm using 11ty to create docs for my stencil component library, and it works fine but there is a bit of a flash on each route/page change while stencil boots up (since the whole layout is made of components)...

So I'm looking for a solution where I can prerender the 11ty site and then use stencil's hydration tool to make it complete. I know there isn't something tailor made for this, but I'm curious if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: it would be nice to include a very simple example that reproduces your problem